# create print() call from for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to generate module calls which should be filled by a for loop. The Problem I'm facing is that I can't insert the output from the loop into the module call as the variable is never inserted before the actual system call happens.

```
    liste = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in liste:

    print (module.i)()
```

I understand that "i" is not converted into "a" and "b" and "c" and is interpreted as function "i" inside of "module". Which doesn't exist. I'm clueless how to perform this simple task without any changes inside the module.

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `getattr()`?

```
for i in liste:
    print getattr(module, i)()
```

Comment: That's it :) Thanks a lot. I didn't thougth about eval. Safed my day. Thanks a lot